# How to log client ips when using nginx as load balancer?

Tags: nginx, logging

I am using nginx with `upstream` for running the webserver and a TURN server on the same port:

```
stream {
    upstream web {
        server 127.0.0.1:4444;
    }
    upstream turn {
        server 127.0.0.1:5349;
    }
    # since 1.13.10
    map $ssl_preread_alpn_protocols $upstream {
        ~\bh2\b         web;
        ~\bhttp/1\.     web;
        default         turn;
    }
}

server {
    listen 4444 ssl http2 http2 http2;
    listen [::]:4444 ssl http2 http2 http2;
    server_name my.domain;
    # (...)
}
```

But using this configuration, I only see `127.0.0.1` in the access log. I tried to set `X-Forwarded-For` in the upstream section, but it is no legal directive there.

What is the best way to log the requests with the real client ip?

Comment: You could use PROXY protocol http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol

Comment: @AlexeyTen For some reason I cannot add `proxy_protocol` to the server section on port 4444. To the main server section on 443 I can add it, but then it is still missing for the upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you tried this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

If yes, have you tried this?

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Comment: There is no `proxy_set_header` directive in streams

Comment: I cannot set any headers in this part of the configuration.